# Xcode corrupted a source code file

Tags: xcode, crash

I was trying to build my project after making some changes to a .m file, say, ResultViewController.m. Suddenly, Xcode crashed and I had to force quit it. Then when i re-opened the project, the file ResultViewController.m got corrupted displaying strange symbols. How can I recover that code ? That was one of the crucial code. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry this has happened to you, since there is no guarantee that you'll be able to recover that file. However, we all get stinged at one time by something like this and afterwards, you tend to appreciate terms like "backup" and "version control".

Comment: This might be better asked on superuser, since the question really boils down to "how to I recover a deleted file on a Mac".

Comment: Thanks for replying, but is there a way to get back the text of the code, like encoding the symbolic code?

Comment: You may have some disk corruption - run Disk First Aid and make sure that your disk does not have problems. Also learn to use Xcode's snapshot capability, and look into Time Machine and/or proper version control.

Comment: I think this happens if the file is open in two panes under XCode 4. I can concur it happens occasionally at least.

Answer (score 0):

if it still compiles/parses without errors, then you may only need to change the text encoding xcode interprets it as (found in the info panel).

Comment: no, it is giving error when compiled. It cannot recognize the encoding of the file.thanks